# Regex: Match repeated char including a single occurence

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to extract chars in below text.

P<AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBB<<XXXX

P<BBBBB<DDDDDDDDDDD<<SSSS

Basically want to extract the text between the first "<" and last "<<". In the above text the result should be

AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBB

and

BBBBB<DDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: If the input is `A<B<<C<D<<E` do you want to match `B` and `D` separately, or just match `B<<C<D`, or is this not something you have to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookarounds with greedy dot, we can try:

```regex
(?<=<).*(?=<<)
```

### Demo

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Tested from my side and working like a charm!!. Thanks a lot.